# Porque mi pagina no se ajustan a las distintas pantallas

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> He intentado centrar lo que es la página pero siempre me queda espacio
>   por ocupar casi siempre como en el boceto de arriba, que pasa?Y tampoco me 
>   sale unas palabras alineadas horizontalmente.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
            <title>Miletra</title>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<ul class="contacto">
    <li>T99</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:kl@example.com">email:kl@example.com</a></li>
</ul>

    <header id="banner">
    <img src="img/x.jpg">
        <div class="continente">
            <h1><div class="a">M</div> <div class="b">i</div> <div class="c">C</div> <div class="d">o</div> <div class="e">c</div> <div class="f">i</div> <div class="g">n</div> <div class="h">a</div>...... 1º DAM</h1>
         </div>
            <nav class="menu">
                <a href="#">Incio</a>
                <a href="#">meu</a>
                <a href="#">sericio a domicilio</a>
                <a href="#">aceca de nosotros</a>
                <a href="formulario.html">rero</a>
            </nav>
    </header>

        <main class="group">
            <section id="blog">
                <div class="contenedor">
                <article class="tamanio1">
                    <img src="img/x.jpg">
                    <h2>Roesa</h2>
                </article>

                <article class="tamanio2">
                <h2>Hola queulo<h2>
                <h3>Hola titulo<h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
                    elit. Quisque l libero ac molestie. In eu nisi 
                    at elit maximus lobortis. </p>
                </article>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor"> 
                <article class="tamanio1">
                    <img src="img/x.jpg">
                    <h2>Sushi</h2>
                </article>

                <article class="tamanio2">
                <h2>Hola que  titulo<h2>
                <h3>Hola que l titulo<h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sibero ac molestie.</p>
                </article>
                </div>      
            </section>

            <aside id="aside">
              <article class="hola">
                    <h4>Recetas populares</h4>
                    <a href="#">Yaoune</a>
                    <a href="#">Okoomiyaki</a>
                    <a href="#">Mizutaki</a>
              </article>
              <article class="adios">
                  <a href="#">j</a>
                  <a href="#">Cona </a>
                  <a href="#">Pa/a>
              </article>
            </aside>
        </main>

<div class="clear"></div>
    <footer>
            <p>&copy; fghdfgh</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
@import url('../css/menu.css');
@import url('../css/banner.css');
{  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:16px;
}

.contacto{
    position:fixed;
    background:white;
    height:40px;
    z-index:100;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;   
    margin: auto;
}

.contacto ul{
    clear: both;
    width:70%;
}

.contacto li{
    margin:10px 50px 10px 50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:25%;
    list-style-type: none; 

}
.contacto li a{
text-decoration:none;
}

 body{
    font-family: myFuente;
    background-image: url("../img/x.jpg");
    max-width:1024px;
    margin-left:165px;
    margin-right:100px;
}

header{
    max-width:1024px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: myFuente;
    src: url(../fonts/Orbitron-Bold.ttf);
}

.continente {
 width: 90%;   
 margin: auto;/*para alinear*/
}

.group {
    position: relative;
    background:white;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
}
section {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 70%;
}
aside {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 25%;
}

header .continente {
    display:table;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background:RGB(192,192,192);
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

footer p {
    padding-top:15px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

menu.css

```
 .continente {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#banner .menu {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:90%;
    left:55%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
#banner .menu a { 
    width:20%;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-left:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}

#banner .menu a:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

banner.css

```
h1 {
    display:flex;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

#banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    right:200px;/*--aqui*/
    margin-bottom:0;
}

#banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#banner .continente{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#banner h1 {
    font-size: 1.750em;
    color: white;
}

#banner {
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        height: 300px;
    }

#banner img {
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Offtopic.  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> Intenta usar siempre codificación UTF-8 para web, me lo agradecerás en un futuro. saludos

Comment: Vale gracias por el consejo @ Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usa `text-align:center;` en body así se alinean las partes o `margin:auto;` `max-width:100%;`

Comment: me ha funcionado con `margin:auto;` Comprobándolo con dos pantallas diferentes. Gracias @BotXtrem Solutions

Comment: `text-align: center` es para alinear texto, ¿a que te refieres con que así se aliean las partes?

Comment: @TripleX por nada amigo es un gusto ayudar

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Romero es un elemento básico de css que puedes usar en un div contenedor  o body

Comment: Una cosa mas, en el **banner.css** las etiquetas `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` no me sale alineados horizontalmente en el banner.

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions El cual no funcionará si solo intentas posicionar divs. Si lo que quieres solamente es alinear el texto entonces si que te funcionará.

Comment: @TripleX Pero no consigo hacerlo encima cada letra tiene que estar de más gran a más pequeño.

Comment: @TripleX que intentas aser con las etiquetas

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions voy a poner una foto arriba.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero <div align:center> contenido</div>  o <div style="text-align:center;">contenido</div>

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions Sí, a lo que me refiero simplemente es que se centrará el contenido que sea texto. Si dentro de ese `div` tuvieras otro `div` o algún elemento de bloque, no te los alinearía.

Comment: @TripleX según entiendo tu código lo que defines es el tamaño de las letras según el id. si solo quieres poner una imagen que se adapte  a la pantalla usa  margin:auto; y max-width:600px; y eso resolvería un poco tu problema

Comment: @FranciscoRomero si amigo usa margin:auto; en el elemento que estará dentro del div y width:80%;